# module not found from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1 with python plugins but this has not been a problem with any other module at all (eg, both locations below show flask, etc). Usually I can `Install Package packagename` which adds it to `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. 
I'm not using a virtual environment as I'm following a course.

I've installed and reinstalled sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy using `pip3 install packagename`
Both show in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

BookModel.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
from settings import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
```

settings.py

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////Users/tomendacott/IdeaPython/BookApp/booksdb.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
```

Error

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/u/IdeaPython/BookApp/BookModel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/u/IdeaPython/BookApp/BookModel.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Comment: `Install Package packagename`? What about `pip`?

Comment: @roganjosh They have both been installed using pip (not pip3) as well

Comment: @roganjosh As the second paragraph says I've installed and reinstalled sqlalchemy and flask-sqlalchemy using pip3. Trying with pip as well was a hail mary and I assume can just be ignored.

Comment: I'm being blind, sorry

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue. According to the [pypy.org](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SQLAlchemy/) ,
I used

pip install -U Flask-SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 0):

OP follow up:
The only way I could get this import working was to manually copy the directories* from where they'd installed with pip3 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages` to `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

I realise this isn't ideal but it works. Again, no virtual environment as currently new to python and following a tutorial.

After this I was getting two errors creating the database
`sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`
`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file`

This line needs 4 forward slashes after sqlite (and one L in sqlite)
`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////Users/username/IdeaPython/BookApp/booksdb.db"`

*flask_sqlalchemy
*Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.0.dist-info (current at time)
*sqlalchemy
*SQLAlchemy-1.3.4.dist-info (current at time)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work through venv. Install venv in the project, activate, install the necessary packages.

If everyone is sure that all required packages are installed. Do

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The IDE will then offer to install the modules from requirements.txt in your virtual environment and everything will work on any machine.